# Please don't migrate "help me draw a syntax tree" questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, migration

Recently, this question was migrated from EL&U to Linguistics.SE:

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27845/syntactic-trees

However, this type of question is *expressly* disallowed by the Linguistics posting guidelines.  Here is the relevant meta post:

https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529/should-we-make-questions-about-specific-syntax-trees-off-topic

What can be done to prevent similar questions from being migrated to Linguistics in the future?

Comment: Despite what the [revision history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/444328/revisions) says, only mods can migrate questions to Linguistics. (ELL and Meta ELU are [the only options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uph4n.png) for regular users.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I migrated that question in response to an explicit flag on it from a serious contributor to the Linguistics SE site specifically asking for the question to be migrated over to Linguistics.

Being myself no more than at best an infrequent contributor to the Linguistics site, and seeing as how the flagger was more than that, I took that flagger up on their request without further investigation. They’re someone who knows what they’re talking about in matters of general linguistics.

The way you “stop” such things is easy: you politely ask that the ELU mod team please coördinate more closely with mod teams of other sites as needed before migrating questions to sites they are not themselves themselves frequent contributors to.

In practice, this means talking to Alenanno, who was sleeping at the time. :)

Comment: Thanks. So in order to coordinate back to the high-profile user on Linguistics, can you name this user, or get them involved here?

Comment: @tripleee No, I cannot.

Comment: @tripleee feel free to unaccept my answer and accept tchrist's. This is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, done so now. I'll (somewhat hesitantly) assume I've done what I can as a regular humble user to coordinate this, and that mods of these respective sites can take it from here if further initiatives are warranted.